# Google Photos API - Can I access existing enrichments?

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

I'm using the Google Photos Java API to create a small program to access the contents of a pre-existing album.  I have been able to get code up and running that can report the album's name, and the media items it contains and so on, but not the text added between photos.  I understand that the API considers these texts a form of enrichment and I can see there are functions for adding such enrichments to an album, but is there any way to list the enrichments already in an album?  Or otherwise access the text a user has previous added between photos via the platform's desktop browser interface?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Google Photos Library API does not provide a way to access existing album enrichments when accessing the contents of an album.

This has been filed as a feature request on the issue tracker for the API. You can 'star' it to draw attention to it and be notified of any updates: https://issuetracker.google.com/129050144